# How to add a second column in a Combobox using Pyqt

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt5

I want two columns to be displayed in my Combobox. How could I do it without going too far into code. This code works but I have only achieved it with one column.

```
    sqlcom2="SELECT cod,name FROM product"
    
    data2 = cur.execute(sqlcom2)
    result2 = cur.fetchall()
    result22 = [i[0] for i in result2]
    self.comboBox.addItems(result22)
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Do you want to layout all items in two columns, or do you need to show two columns with each row displaying the pair of results of your query?

Comment: show two columns with each row displaying the pair of results of the query. Each item in the PRODUCT table has its respective code. I want to show both data.

Answer (score 0):

QComboBox doesn't normally allow to show more than one column of items as its [`view()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#view) is normally a QListView. In order to show more contents, you can use a QTableView instead, but this requires adding more items for each row, so the basic `addItem()` or `addItems()` cannot be used, so items must be added to the combobox *model* instead.

Even if QComboBox currently uses a QStandardItemModel, this might change in the future, so it's better to create your own QStandardItemModel and set that model for the combo.

Then, QComboBox is able to use models with multiple columns (the default is column 0) and the currently used column can be changed using [`setModelColumn()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#modelColumn-prop), but you need to ensure that whenever the user selects an item in a different column the combobox column is update accordingly. In order to do that, a subclass of QTableView is usually the best approach, as it allows to override the methods required to notify the combo about the column change.

There's also another problem: QComboBox uses its own width to automatically resize the popup width. While for single column popup this is not a big problem, if multiple columns are going to be shown, it's possible that only the first column will be shown.
To solve this issue you can set a minimum size for the table view within the `showEvent` of the table; note that this is generally *not* a suggested approach, but it is acceptable for this specific case and for the sake of simplicity. Also consider that I'm using the [`defaultSectionSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#defaultSectionSize-prop) property, and you might prefer to ensure that the columns resize themselves according to the contents, but since that is a more and slightly unrelated topic that might add more complexity to the implementation, I'll not address it in this answer.

```
class ComboTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, comboBox):
        super().__init__()
        self.comboBox = comboBox
        self.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.activated.connect(self.updateComboColumn)

    def updateComboColumn(self, index):
        if (index.isValid() and 
            index.flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled and 
            index.flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable):
                self.comboBox.setModelColumn(index.column())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.updateComboColumn(self.indexAt(event.pos()))
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        w = self.horizontalHeader().defaultSectionSize() * self.model().columnCount()
        if self.model().rowCount() > self.comboBox.maxVisibleItems():
            w += self.verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width()
        self.setMinimumWidth(w)


class SomeWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.comboTableView = ComboTableView(self.comboBox)
        self.comboBox.setView(self.comboTableView)
        comboModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.comboBox.setModel(comboModel)
        # ...

        sqlcom2="SELECT cod,name FROM product"
    
        data2 = cur.execute(sqlcom2)
        result2 = cur.fetchall()
        for rowValues in result2:
            items = []
            for value in rowValues:
                items.append(QtGui.QStandardItem(value))
            comboModel.appendRow(items)
```

Finally, you can also implement "horizontal" keyboard navigation within the combo so that the user can switch between columns using the arrow keys, and that can be done by installing an event filter that manages arrow keys.

```
class SomeWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.comboBox.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.comboBox and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
                column = min(
                    self.comboBox.modelColumn() + 1, 
                    self.comboBox.model().columnCount() - 1
                    )
                self.comboBox.setModelColumn(column)
            elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
                column = max(0, self.comboBox.modelColumn() - 1)
                self.comboBox.setModelColumn(column)
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```